# Secured Cron Job for Google App Engine fails to start (Node js)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cron

I am struggling with a cron job with secured URL in google app engine.
As soon as I add *login:admin* in the *app.yaml*, the job fails to start (otherwise it works like a charm).

Here is my code:

- app.js

  ```js
  const express = require('express');
  const app = express();

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Hello, world!').end();
  });

  app.get('/admin', function(req, res){
   res.status(200).send('Hello, admin!').end();
  });


  // Start the server
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
    console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
  });
  ```
- app.yaml

  ```js
  runtime: nodejs
  env: flex

  handlers:
  - url: /
    script: app.js
    
  - url: /admin
    login: admin
    script: app.js
  ```
- cron.yaml

  ```js
  cron:
  - description: daily summary job
    url: /admin
    schedule: every 12 mins
    target: default
  ```

And the result:
[cron failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG4eQ.png)

Any hint on what I am missing?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `login` setting under `handlers` is now deprecated for the App Engine flexible environment.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/upgrading

`login: admin` should be removed from your app.yaml.

You can still secure the url by checking for the X-Appengine-Cron header in your code.

```
app.get('/admin', function(req, res){
    if (req.get('X-Appengine-Cron') !== 'true') {
         return res.status(401).end();
    }
    res.status(200).send('Hello, admin!');
});
```

Per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/cron#securing_urls_for_cron)

> The X-Appengine-Cron header is set internally by Google App Engine. If your request handler finds this header it can trust that the request is a cron request. If the header is present in an external user request to your app, it is stripped, except for requests from logged in administrators of the application, who are allowed to set the header for testing purposes.